# Click event not registering with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a MVC 4 application with Basic template. In the _layout.cshtml I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("body").on({
                // When ajaxStart is fired, add 'loading' to body class
                ajaxStart: function () {
                    $(this).addClass("loading");
                },
                // When ajaxStop is fired, remove 'loading' from body class
                ajaxStop: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("loading");
                }
            });

            $("a").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass("loading");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

And the HTML in the same:

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <div class="modal"></div>
</body>
```

I created a HomeController which has just the code given by MVC.
In the Index view all I have is this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<a href="#">some <span class="red">text</span></a>
```

I am trying to understand on how to implement a loader whenever a link or an ajax request is made across the application.

Got a lot of help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314885/how-to-use-handle-a-loader-in-an-mvc-app#18315726) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation/1964871#1964871).

The above code is not showing the loader when the link is clicked, there aren't any ajax calls as of now.
This is a very simple thing for a lot of jQuery gurus out there but I am having a hard time understanding the events hookup using jQuery so I am trying to learn with small baby steps.

Can someone guide me on how to show the loader and hide it?

Appreciate your help.
Regards.

Comment: whether those `a` elements are created dynamically?

Comment: Well you need to take the `a` click event out of the first on event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if a is not created dyanmically, if a is created on runtime then need to bind while creation time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("body").on({
            // When ajaxStart is fired, add 'loading' to body class
            ajaxStart: function () {
                $(this).addClass("loading");
            },
            // When ajaxStop is fired, remove 'loading' from body class
            ajaxStop: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("loading");
            }
        });

        $("a").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("loading");
        });
    });

</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mHYU/1/)

Comment: Not working, tried putting an alert instead just for checks, that doesn't show up either.

Comment: and what isn't working? It IS adding the class "loading" the the `A` element.

Answer (score 0):

If a is created dynamicly, you cannot use click() function. Try this one

```
 $("a").on('click',function () {
            $(this).addClass("loading");
        });
```